# Change font of selection in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to create a very small macro to change the format (text size and font) in Powerpoint.

I have tried using this code taken from a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669448/how-to-change-the-font-of-a-selection-in-powerpoint-2013-with-vba).  The code works, just not when the selected text is in a smart art graphic.  I get an error message that says `This Member can only be accessed for a single shape.`

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Courier New"
    .Bold = msoTrue
End With
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll get that error if more than one shape within the smartart is selected. If you select one at a time, your code works as expected. Are you trying to change all of the text in a piece of smartart or a selected subset of the shapes?

Comment: That's weird because I'll be selecting the text from two bullets at once. Just a selected subset.

Comment: So you're selecting several lines of text from within one of the shapes in the smartart as opposed to selecting several of the shapes?

Comment: Exactly, This is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: I'm hitting dead-ends here. The OM doesn't seem to support any way of accessing more than the text in the first shape.